# Copy sheet to folder if cell matches folder id - apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to this. I've been looking for the answer for a couple of days now but can't seem to find it.

I need to copy a sheet to folder, where value in the cell matches the folder ID(name).

This is what I have so far:

```
function copyDocument() {
     
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get current active spreadsheet.
    var sstocopy = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); // Get spreadsheet with DriveApp.

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PO"); // Get current active sheet.
    var project = sheet.getRange("E6").getValue(); // gets project name in file name
    var poNumber = sheet.getRange("C6").getValue(); // gets po number in file name

    var folderId = sheet.getRange(6,5).getValue();//this is wrong this range is the range to get project number not folderId
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); // Get the ID of the folder where you will place a copy of the spreadsheet.
   
    sstocopy.makeCopy('PO ' + project + " (" + poNumber + ")",folder); // Make a copy of the spreadsheet in the destination folder.

}
```

It is throwing an error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.

If I manually enter the folder id, it works.

Thank you for your help.

The folder diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2CBy.jpg

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing the sheet or a sample sheet ? I believe problem is with the cell value or you are not getting the value of folder id from correct cell.

Comment: The link to sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D7WVGrKrhOuAaAh6gFnDNNdKhCScFGFFbifi2r_DHHg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: permissions ? @Sessionone

Comment: permissions updated, sorry.

Comment: Can you show us what the id in the sheet looks like?

Comment: It is text, name of a project. I guess that is the problem? Folder id cannot be text?

Comment: still no access

Comment: Sorry, should work now

Comment: yeah, that E6 cell is not a valid folder id. If you are looking to get the folder by name then check the relevant method: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function copyDocument() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var sstocopy = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());    
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var project = sheet.getRange("E6").getValue();
    var poNumber = sheet.getRange("C6").getValue();     
    var folderId = sheet.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);  
    if(folder)sstocopy.makeCopy(`PO ${project} (${poNumber})`,folder);    
}
```

From the official documentation:

makeCopy(name, destination)
Creates a copy of the file in the destination directory and names it with the name provided.

| Parameters |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Type | Description |
| name | String | The filename that should be applied to the new copy. |
| destination | Folder | The directory to copy the file into. |

[makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))

Are you trying to do something like this:

[image]

If so please explain how you wish it to work

Comment: Thanks, still throws the same error...

Comment: I just noticed that row 6 col 5 is the same as project E6. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, E6 is the name of the project. So, the copy should go to the folder with the same name... The same value is used to rename the copy.

Comment: Yes but getRange(6,5) is E6 so your getting the project name instead of the id.  I changed the code to put the folder id in A1 and it now works.

Comment: Read the comment that I put next to this line: `var folderId = sheet.getRange(6,5).getValue();` in your question 6,5 is E6  So your looking for the id in the wrong place and you didn't tell us where it is located so I picked A1

Comment: Sorry, by saying folder id, I mean folder name, which, as it appears, seems to be the problem. So, if value in E6 matches with a folder name in drive, the copy should go to that folder.

Comment: The second parameter in makeCopy is the folder not the folder name.

Comment: Ok... But how do I match the project name in E6 with the folder name and make a copy in that folder?...

Comment: Perhaps with [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setName(String)) function. Or manually when you create it or if you wish to you could create subfolders of a main folder named Projects with sub folders that have specific projects names that have the same name as the folder.

Comment: Well, I just did that, added folder IDs to every single project. When I choose a project to make the PO for, the folder ID is being fetched from dependent dropdown. But, originally I wanted to avoid this. Yes, the project folders are within a master folder. I have managed so far to get the names of the folders within the master folder, but can't figure out how to match value in E6 with the folder name...Thank you anyway.

Comment: Did you click on the link in my last comment?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think I do understand what goes where. Added link to my diagram, can't upload photos yet.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now with the image.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of the sheet that your extracting data from and perhaps explain the logic behind it.